# Is the inflection of the Latin words in today's science similar to that of classical Latin, or English?

Tags: contemporary-latin, science, scientific-names, biology, medicine

There are Latin words created and used in today's sciences (e.g. biology, medicine, ...). Does the inflection of such words follow the inflection rules in classical Latin? Since they are often used in the context of English, and the inflection in classical Latin is complicated, it would be reasonable if their inflection follows simplified rules such as those for English.

Answer (score 5):

Words used in a Latin context are inflected as Latin, and words used in an English context are inflected as English.

While people might pluralize "nucleus" as "nuclei", nobody says "from the nucleis" or "of the nucleorum". That sort of inflection simply isn't used in English. On the other hand, we have phrases like "ad hominem" instead of "ad homo" because that word is being used in a Latin context (as the argument of *ad*), not an English one. (Same with gender agreement in biology, sometimes, and the genitive case in astronomy.)